# How Can I move the map to right side without effecting the text?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjtvn.png)
The code is right here

```
        <div class="row w-100">
        <div class="col-lg-6 my-4 offset-lg-1">
            <iframe src="#" 
            width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="true" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 my-4 offset-lg-1">
          <div>
            <h6>This map is embedded in a 6 column layout</h6>
            <p>Try to resize your browser window - you will see that it starts to take up 12 columns on
              screens smaller than 992px.</p>
            <p>This useful feature helps to make your embedded map responsive (<strong>mobile
                friendly</strong>). You can customize responsive behavior with the use of <a
                href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/layout/breakpoints/">breakpoints</a>.</p>
            <p>This text looks so nice because it's <strong>vertically centered</strong> you can achieve
              this effect using the <a
                href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/layout/vertical-alignment/">vertical
                alignment</a> layout option.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want the map and the text are shown side by side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row w-100">
    <!-- remove col-lg-6 and add just col class-->
    <!-- Move or create the div containing the image here-->
    <div class="my-4 offset-lg-1 col">
      <img
        src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
        alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- remove col-lg-6 and add just col class-->
    <div class="my-4 offset-lg-1 col">
      <div>
        <h6>This map is embedded in a 6 column layout</h6>
        <p>Try to resize your browser window - you will see that it starts to take up 12 columns on
          screens smaller than 992px.</p>
        <p>This useful feature helps to make your embedded map responsive (<strong>mobile
            friendly</strong>). You can customize responsive behavior with the use of <a
            href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/layout/breakpoints/">breakpoints</a>.</p>
        <p>This text looks so nice because it's <strong>vertically centered</strong> you can achieve
          this effect using the <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/layout/vertical-alignment/">vertical
            alignment</a> layout option.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can learn more about columns in [Boot strap columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/columns/)